# Gradle: Multi-projects & build WAR file

Tags: java, gwt, gradle

I'm changing our project to use gradle as the build tool but am struggling with 2 issues;

Context: It is a multi-project gradle configuration

```
:project-root
------:client //GWT Java Files & GWT Centric resources, e.g. CSS, Images, ui-xml etc..
------:server //Server based logic, e.g. controllers, services, repositories etc.
------:web-app//NON GWT resources for the web-app, e.g. , web.xml, static pages, images
```

1: To get the `gwtCompile` task to run in the `:client build.gradle`, I am adding it as a dependency on the war task, like so:

```
war{
    dependsOn ':client:compileGwt'
    from {'src/main/root-content'}
    webInf {from 'src/main/web-inf-content'}
}
```

I don't like this so is there a simpler way in doing this so that the `gwtCompile` task gets called when the `javaCompile` tasks finishes in the `:client` project so the GWT Compiler has access to the generated bytecode? By simply putting `compile project(':client')` in :web-app dependencies calls the `javaCompile` but not the `gwtCompile` task (as I would have expected)..

2: I struggling in getting the GWT JavaScript output from the `:client` project and for these files to be copied into the war file. I need something like the following in the `from` property:

```
war{
    from {'src/main/root-content','$:CLIENT/gwt-compiler-js-output-dir-as-declared-in-client-build-file}
    webInf {from 'src/main/web-inf-content'}
}
```

Many Thanks in advance,

Ian.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your own task dependencies manually, provided you're not introducing dependency issues. :) Have you tried doing something like this?

```
javaCompile.dependsOn(project(':yourproject').taskName)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many thanks - however :yourproject.taskname needs to run after the javaCompile tasks place..

Comment: So it should be inverted?

`taskName.dependsOn(project(':theOtherProject').javaCompile)`